# how do i rename file using loopback storage service

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am stuck how to rename the uploaded file to server.
don't know how to rename the file and send that url further.

Using [loopback-storage-service]

Do i make changes in container model?
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To rename create a file inside your loopback `boot` folder

> boot/renameFile.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  //Function for checking the file type..
  app.dataSources.presImage.connector.getFilename = function(file, req, res) {
     //Return the new FileName
     return 'NEW_FILENAME.JPG'
 }

}//exports
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)'s github page, it says

> Angular File Upload is a module for the AngularJS framework. Supports drag-n-drop upload, upload progress, validation filters and a file upload queue. It supports native HTML5 uploads, but degrades to a legacy iframe upload method for older browsers. Works with any server side platform which supports standard HTML form uploads.

I also checked [angular-file-upload.js](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/angular-file-upload.js), there is no provision for renaming in it.

I would recommend to upload the file first and then using your server side code rename it for you, it will be easier that way.

**Update :** Found this on its github issues - [Is it possible to rename the file before upload?](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/issues/138)

Comment: i am using loopback-storage-service-provider loopback.io , kindly help how to do that